# desktop application data send to web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, desktop-application, katana

Work on .net application my application has one **desktop**(windows form) and **web application**(MVC5), in desktop application have one button, client on button want to display one image in my web application.

Is there any idea how to do ?

Answer (score 1):

What about using `SignalR`.
You can make connection between your `Desktop App` and `Web App`
then you can call any method you need from `Desktop` to `Web` and vice versa.

> ASP.NET SignalR is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies
>   the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications.
>   Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server code push
>   content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, rather
>   than having the server wait for a client to request new data

Read more here: [Asp.net SignalR.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

Answer (score -1):

Through the webapi it will works.